# We have browser Prefixes for text-align: -webkit-right;(Google and safari)text-align: -moz-right;(Firefox)text-align: -o-right;(Opera).What is for IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

We have browser prefixes or hacks for

```
(for Google and Safari)  text-align: -webkit-right;
(for Firefox)            text-align: -moz-right;
(for Opera)              text-align: -o-right;
```

**What is for IE?**

Below code working for me in chrome,Mozilla,safari and opera but in IE text is not coming on right....Any Answer ?

```
 style="display: table-cell; width: 25%; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: -webkit-right;text-align: -moz-right;text-align: -o-right"
```

Comment: It's `-ms` see http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm

Comment: Is there any reason why to do it?

Comment: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#Browser_compatibility) "Both WebKit and Gecko supports a prefixed version of left, center, and right, that applies not only to inline content but also to block elements. This is used to implement the legacy align attributes on some table-related element. *Do not use these on production Web sites.*"

Comment: I dont think these are hacks they are browser prefixes. you also have your `-webkit-` in the wrong place. if `text-align` needed one it would be `-webkit-text-align`

Comment: -ms is not working I already did that...

Comment: @Andrew: A hack is anything that is being used for something it wasn't intended for. And vendor prefixes don't have to be on property names, they can be on values.

Answer (score 0):

> These browser prefixes are needed as the browsers experiment and test out their implementations of the newer CSS3 properties. Sometimes all the prefixes are not always needed, but it usually does not hurt to include them, as long as you make sure to put the **non-prefixed version last**.

```
text-align: -webkit-right;
text-align: -moz-right;
text-align: -o-right; 
text-align: -ms-right;
text-align: right;
```

There are several reasons why this is important, but I’m not going to get into that here. Just make it a rule to always include the non-prefixed version and put it at the end.

> Internet Explorer 9 supports many (but not all) of the favorite CSS3 properties. You can use border-radius without any vendor-prefix, for example.

Some properties are so far along in development, that some browsers are dropping the prefix. Border-radius is one property that is pretty well developed at this point. The latest versions of major browsers all seem to support it without the vendor-prefixes. Keeping them in the code, however, allows you to make sure users who don’t update their browsers, will still be served.

Comment: "put the non-prefixed version last" is not correct in this case, because "right" and "-webkit-right" do not behave the same way. If you put the non-prefixed version last, it will override the prefixed version.